# How to implement an ontology for a simple website

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, rdflib, triplestore

I currently have developed a few websites (using Django, Flask, Symfony, etc...).  I have also developed Ontologies using semantic software (PoolParty) for enterprise size companies.

I would like to use a small ontology to link data currently in the database of a small website.  I do not want it connected to the semantic web.  I want to keep all data in relational databases, but link the data with an ontology.

Is there a way to do this?  Say if I have a simple flask or django app, is there a way to put an ontology and triplestore on top?

Comment: Short answer is yes, but a detailed answer really needs more details on what you wish to do with the ontology.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is what the technology stack look like?  If I have a Django App with a form to enter new Items storing them in a MySQL database, what technology would I use to link the new item to previously entered items in an ontology?  I would also want another Django page with a search box where I could search for items in the database and retrieve them along with other items linked by the ontology.

Comment: You would need to use RDF and SPARQL libraries to access your ontology .owl file extension.